# Kafka Producer jmx metrics missing

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, prometheus, kafka-producer-api, openshift-origin

We have Spring Boot applications deployed on OKD (The Origin Community Distribution of Kubernetes that powers Red Hat OpenShift). Without much tweaking by devops team, we got in prometheus scraped kafka consumer metrics from kubernetes-service-endpoints exporter job, as well as some producer metrics, but only for kafka connect api, not for standard kafka producer api. This is I guess a configuration for that job:

https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml

What is needed to change in scrape config in order to collect what's been missing?

Comment: Spring boot wouldn't have kafka connect metrics. Are you scraping the actuator endpoint or using JMX exporter?

Comment: Take a look at [Monitoring Kafka with Prometheus and Grafana](https://github.com/ibm-cloud-architecture/refarch-eda/blob/master/docs/kafka/monitoring.md).

Comment: @cricket_007 We are scraping the actuator endpoint provided by Micrometer Prometheus Registry, like this https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-actuator-metrics-monitoring-dashboard-prometheus-grafana/

Answer (score 1):

This [issue](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1095) with micrometer is the source of the problem.

So, we could add jmx exporter, or wait for the issue resolution.